# Unknown column in 'field list' php/mySQL but the field DOES exist.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query in PHP which I call from an Android app.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
                `asset`.`idasset`,
                `asset`.`idlocation`,
                `asset`.`asset_barcode`,
                `asset`.`asset_number`,
                `asset`.`category_name`,
                `asset`.`make`,
                `asset`.`model`,
                `asset`.`serial_number`,
                `asset`.`iduser`,
                `asset`.`idcost_centre`,
                `asset`.`idcondition`,
                `asset`.`idstatus`,
                `asset`.`latitude`,
                `asset`.`longitude`,
                `asset`.`asset_description`
                from `asset`";
```

This is the response I receive from the call in Android Studio console:

```
D/RAW RESPONSE: Notice: Unknown column 'asset.idlocation' in 'field list'
```

But that field does exist.
Here's the full create statement I reverse copied to clipboard in MySQLWorkbench.

```
CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `idasset` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idlocation` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asset_barcode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asset_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asset_description` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `make` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serial_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iduser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idcost_centre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idcondition` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idstatus` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idasset`),
  KEY `cost_center_fk_idx` (`idcost_centre`),
  KEY `iduser_fk_idx` (`iduser`),
  KEY `category_name_fk_idx` (`category_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `category_name_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`category_name`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `iduser_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`iduser`) REFERENCES `user` (`iduser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=93 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I run that exact raw query in PHPMyAdmin or MySQLWorkbench it works, but not in PHP.

If I swap around the sequence of the fields I also get the same error with:

```
`asset`.`asset_description` 
`asset`.`latitude`,
`asset`.`longitude`,
```

But all the other fields are fine.
Strange thing is this query worked a few weeks ago.
Am I missing something?
I don't have any ideas. 
Starting to think its a PHP or MySQL setup or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as time is not on my side.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd back-tick disappeared?

Comment: Mybe you connect to an other db as you expected

Comment: Thanks for the response, not sure where you're referring to.

Comment: Have you tried the query without the table prefixes? Like `select idasset, idlocation, ... from asset`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry silly mistake, I did point to another DB.